# Redshift TO_CHAR change date to string

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
select * from tableA where to_char(date,"yyyyMMdd") = "20221220"
```

The expected result is change the date value from date to string by using to_char so that it can performs the condition = "20221220"

the data type for the date colunm is timestamp without time zone in redshift

ERROR: column "yyyymm" does not exist in tableA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in Redshift (and SQL in general) are denoted with single quotes('), not double quotes (").  Double quotes denote column or table names that need to be quoted.  Changing to single quotes should fix this up - 'YYYYMMDD'

A performance issue with the query as written is that you should compare column values in its native format in WHERE clauses.  This allows Redshift to use its metadata for improved query performance.  Also Redshift also only needs to perform the cast of the literal to date once but in your query every value of date needs to be converted to a string - less work means faster execution.  You really should write the WHERE clause as:

```
WHERE date = '2022-12-20'::date
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. May i know is ::date can convert a string '2022-12-20' to a date format? If i want to select only date in 12 month, `WHERE date like '2022-12-%'::date` why is this code not working?

Comment: Yes, :: is shorthand for CAST.  No, you cannot wildcard but there are a couple of ways to state this.  "WHERE date >= '2022-12-01' AND date <= '2022-12-31'" will work or you can use "WHERE date between  '2022-12-01' AND 2022-12-31'".  There are other ways to do this but these will maintain the Redshift metadata optimization.